# Android 10 keychain not offering installed client certificate in browser

Tags: android, apache, ssl, client-certificates

On Android 10, with a .p12 client certificate installed (includes user key, user cert and CA cert), going to a URL in Chrome or FF that requests a client cert, the KeyChain does not prompt to select an installed cert to use. The KeyChain dialog flashes for a split second, but has no certs listed, and just goes to and error:  `ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT`.

This process works on Android 9 and below with the same .p12 without issue, along with Desktop browsers on various platforms, so the .p12 and Apache config for requesting the client cert would appear valid.

All I can find that might relate to a change in Android 10 is:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-all#keychain

Unfortunately, it's unclear as to what might be required to change and whether it's something in the Apache config or in the .p12 itself.

Happy to provide more details if anyone has any ideas, rather than just dumping everything I can think of here from the start.

**Amendment:**

After much testing, it appears to be that Android 10 doesn't seem to like client certs issued by an intermediate CA cert.

Despite putting the full chain into the .p12 (root CA cert, intermediate CA cert and leaf cert), the KeyChain on Android 10 doesn't offer up the installed cert when a client cert is requested by a site.

The same root CA issuing a leaf cert with the same extension and attributes as above, then put into a .p12 (root CA cert and leaf cert) does then work.

Unfortunately, I need to use the intermediate to issue the leaf certs, but I've no idea why this doesn't seem to work just on Android 10!  Unsure if this is a bug or something else specific is required to get it working.

I've also tried installing the Root CA cert and intermediate CA cert separately, as the "Trusted Credentials (User)", but it makes no difference.

Leaf cert extension attributes are:

keyUsage                = digitalSignature
extendedKeyUsage        = clientAuth

Comment: `After much testing, it appears to be that Android 10 doesn't seem to like client certs issued by an intermediate CA cert.` - I had to install the intermediate certificate in Android's trustStore too, so it was working as soon as I had all 4 things installed: Root CA Certificate, Intermediate Certificate, User key, User certificate (combined in one pfx with User key, CA and Intermediate as separate .pem files).

Comment: Nope, it has been cached somewhere. After opening a clean browser session, authentication didn't work when nginx had just the Root CA cert configured. When configuring the chain (root and intermediate) it works - but that's a configuration nightmare to have all intermediate certificates in the web server's trustStore...

Comment: Johannes, I installed the root CA cert and intermediate cert in "Trusted Credentials (User)" under Settings (then encryption/security off the top of my head) on Android 10.

The .p12 package installed on Android 10 also had the root CA cert, intermediate cert and user/leaf cert, plus user/leaf key, but still this didn't work.

The web server, Apache in my case, uses the RootCA cert to request the client cert from the client connecting.  The web server shouldn't need an intermediate cert, as anything below the RootCA needs to be valid, i.e. any intermediate and any user/leaf cert.

Comment: @ChrisSeal did you get to the bottom of this? I'm facing the same issue now

Comment: @DevNewb afraid not - it appears to be a legit bug that is resolved in Android v11. I’ve raised it with the Google Android developers: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/166132182

Comment: @ChrisSeal Were you using Firefox by any chance? I've wasted 2 days and questioned my sanity just to learn that it DOES work in Chrome. Firefox has issue open to support client certs https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/fenix/issues/13988

Comment: @DevNewb no, it was the default Chrome on Android. With the info above and that in the issue tracker above, I’ve yet to find a way to use a client certificate issued by an intermediate CA on Android 10, vs it working fine on v9 and v11.